# System/38 database programming: did it allow duplicate records?

Tags: sql, ibm-midrange

Anybody out there remember the System/38? This is specifically a vintage question. I already know the answer for AS/400, iSeries and later.

Did the S/38 allow duplicate records in database files:

- for PFs. LFs, JFs?
- for the results of queries from Query/38 or OPNQRYF?

I'm asking because the current documentation I see on IBM support centre for AS/400 KEYFLD and UNIQUEKEY params to OPNQRYF is unclear (and probably isn't telling me what S/38 used to do).

SQL can return duplicate records from a SELECT (unless you specify DISTINCT). My (unreliable) memory tells me that as of mid-1980's S/38 did not.

Comment: I don't recall UNIQUE ever being anything but optional.

Comment: Thx. ?The param to OPNQRYF is UNIQUEKEY. "If there are multiple query records with the same values for ... the key fields, only the first such record is available through the open query file." So you'd never see duplicate records(?) Quote from https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/opnqryf.htm

Comment: If you specify **other than** UNIQUEKEY(*NONE), you shouldn't see duplicates in the result set. Note that the default is UNIQUEKEY(*NONE) and duplicates are allowed. Also, OPNQRYF was introduced fairly late, IIRC.

Comment: Thx. I used OPNQRYF in '82. Is that what you mean by late? I rather thought it was the raw query engine that underpinned LFs, JFs, Query/38 and SQL (later on the AS/400).

Comment: OPNQRYF was added at least a couple releases into CPF. Actually, I was thinking it was as late as Release 5, but not sure. It did pre-date SEQUEL, though, and made quite a welcome splash on announcement.

Answer (score 0):

The DDS for sys38 isnt very different from the 400.  If you use *UNIQUE in the DDS file definition AND as long as the file is KEYED... any program trying to hit that file for a write will crash with a duplicate key.

Comment: Thanks Harley, but you're not answering the question I put. Of course *UNIQUE and KEYED together mean 'no duplicates'. Could you omit *UNIQUE and then be allowed duplicates? If not, could you omit *UNIQUE and omit KEYED then be allowed duplicates?

Comment: If *unique  is gone, then Im pretty sure that you can get dups.  Keyed is just how the file is organized(but you knew that).  If you have *unique on the base PF and add logical files over it, every key group will be checked as dup for every keyed logical. You could build the file without unique or keyed and put logicals over that. Dups abounding.  =)